# Magento2 add extra cost to shipping method on customer selected option radio button on checkout shipping form

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, shipping-address, multishipping, magento-shipping

We need to add extra Cost to shipping method, when customer select one of the input radio button on the custom  shipping form.

Answer (score 5):

we can add plugin for Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate">
    <plugin name="custom_shipping_price" type="<vendor>\<module>\Plugin\Quote\Address\Rate"/>
</type>
```

In <module>\Plugin\Quote\Address\Rate Class add after method on afterImportShippingRate

```
public function afterImportShippingRate(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate $subject, $result, $rate)
{
    if ($rate instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method) {
        if($result->getCode() == 'custom_shipping_method_code') {
            $result->setCode('<custom_shipping_method_code>')->setPrice('<calculated_custome_price>');
           
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

we can change the shipping method price here(<custom_shipping_method_code>) on our <custom_shipping_method_code>.

> change the <custom_shipping_method_code> like flatrate_flatrate

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: You can do this by overriding address rate file in your custom module.
Step 2: Create Namespace/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" type="Namespace\Module\Model\OfflineShipping\Carrier\Flatrate" />
</config>
```

Step 3: Modify the as per requirement into your custom file filepath,
app\code\Namespace\Module\Model\OfflineShipping\Carrier\Flatrate.php